# What is the latest version of CiviVolunteer?

Tags: drupal, 4.7, civivolunteer

I have version 4.7.21-2.2.3 of CiviVolunteer installed, but when I look at the list of extensions Civi recommends updating to 4.7.31-2.3.0  I am running 4.7.27 by the way, so I'm assuming that this release doesn't apply.  Is that correct? The list of releases at https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer adds to the confusion as the 2.3.0 version was released *before* the 2.2.3 version.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4):

I think there is confusion on release date. Version 4.7.31-2.3.0 was [released](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/releases) on March 2018 not March 2017. I guess the maintainer forgot to update the year to 2018 in info.xml file.

HTH

Pradeep